# How to download a non-public file (video) from Google Cloud Storage using webpage generated by Google Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a HTTP Google Cloud Function that returns a web page (HTML5 and JavaScript).
The web page successfully displays and auto-plays a small/short video clip stored in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.  I need a link or button (or whatever) for the user to click that downloads the video clip file.  The download currently works when the file is in a public bucket.  But it does not work when the file is in a "private" (non-public) bucket.

A public sample of the GCF is at https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net/testDownloadClip.
For simplicity, the video tag to display and auto-play the video has been omitted from this public sample.  The sample page has two links and two buttons (one link and one button for the public version of the video file, one link and one button for the private version of the video file).

Unfortunately, the public and private links play the video instead of downloading the video file.
However, I found a reference to a javascript function that does work to download the public file but does not work to download the private file.

Both the public and private bucket have CORS origin set:

```
gsutil cors get gs://public.awarenet.us
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600,"method": ["GET"], "origin":["https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net"]}]

gsutil cors get gs://private.awarenet.us
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600,"method": ["GET"], "origin":["https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net"]}]
```

**Clicking the "public download" *button* successfully downloads the file and shows this on the Network tab in Chrome:**

```
Request URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/public.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 142.251.33.48:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-origin: https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding, X-GUploader-UploadID, X-Google-Trace
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: public, max-age=3600
content-length: 136939
content-type: video/mp4
date: Sun, 06 Nov 2022 22:35:33 GMT
etag: "065400d7073e29b671e510bf096264fc"
expires: Sun, 06 Nov 2022 23:35:33 GMT
last-modified: Sun, 06 Nov 2022 22:28:25 GMT
server: UploadServer
vary: Origin
x-goog-generation: 1667773705396016
x-goog-hash: crc32c=CEFqXA==
x-goog-hash: md5=BlQA1wc+KbZx5RC/CWJk/A==
x-goog-metageneration: 1
x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
x-goog-stored-content-length: 136939
x-guploader-uploadid: ADPycdvhxvfiD87l3tIDyXXCS3qzkeueIlS8vYbVbjMuF_Md6IYRBqg14iLJuNlEdIsHHGKnC4_b1wrlJirVfKK4eMkjtw

Request Headers
:authority: storage.googleapis.com
:method: GET
:path: /public.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
origin: https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net
referer: https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-client-data: CJW2yQEIorbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIlqHLAQjsu8wBCNW8zAEIxeHMAQj26swBCPDtzAEI/u3MAQ==
Decoded:
message ClientVariations {
  // Active client experiment variation IDs.
  repeated int32 variation_id = [3300117, 3300130, 3300164, 3313321, 3330198, 3349996, 3350101, 3354821, 3356022, 3356400, 3356414];
}
```

**Clicking the "private download" *button* fails to download the file and shows this on the Console tab of Chrome:**

```
Access to fetch at 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/private.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4' from origin 'https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
testDownloadClip:31          GET https://storage.cloud.google.com/private.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED 302
downloadClip @ testDownloadClip:31
onclick @ testDownloadClip:24
```

**Also, when the "private download" button fails, it shows this on the Network tab of Chrome:**

```
Request URL: https://storage.cloud.google.com/private.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
content-length: 0
content-type: application/binary
cross-origin-opener-policy-report-only: same-origin; report-to="coop_82ccfd3e8dff6a1e039e9fb749e256f0"
date: Sun, 06 Nov 2022 22:38:26 GMT
location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cds&passive=1209600&continue=https://storage.cloud.google.com/private.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4&followup=https://storage.cloud.google.com/private.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4
report-to: {"group":"coop_82ccfd3e8dff6a1e039e9fb749e256f0","max_age":2592000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/report-to/82ccfd3e8dff6a1e039e9fb749e256f0"}]}
server: ESF
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 0

Request Headers
:authority: storage.cloud.google.com
:method: GET
:path: /private.awarenet.us/testvideo3.mp4
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
origin: https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net
referer: https://us-central1-awarenet.cloudfunctions.net/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-client-data: CJW2yQEIorbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIlqHLAQjsu8wBCNW8zAEIxeHMAQj26swBCPDtzAEI/u3MAQ==
Decoded:
message ClientVariations {
  // Active client experiment variation IDs.
  repeated int32 variation_id = [3300117, 3300130, 3300164, 3313321, 3330198, 3349996, 3350101, 3354821, 3356022, 3356400, 3356414];
}
```

Why is the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing from the private file??

What can be done to make the download of the private file successful?

Comment: Did you try as it recommends? Add 'no-cors' to your request header.

Comment: @Tim Where is it recommended to add "no-cors" to the request header?
This info seems to say "no-cors" is a bad idea. https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: That was the suggestion from your console error. It is true that disabling CORS is generally a bad idea in a production environment, but it can help during development to narrow down other issues.

Comment: Interesting that when I click the "private download" link, I get an authorization error. But if I click the button, I get the CORS error. Seems the issue is coming from how the function is called.

Comment: @Tim Thanks.  With no-cors, I still get a request status 302.

Comment: This page https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin
has the statement "The authenticated browser download endpoint storage.cloud.google.com does not allow CORS requests. Note that the Google Cloud console provides this endpoint for each object's public URL link."
That seems to say using the authenticated URL for the file will not work when cross-origin.

Comment: Have you found solution? if so can you share your solution as answer?